# Can I compile and run a .NET MVC 5 project from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

This is in case I got a VisualStudio2015 project and want a quick code modification and compilation. This will be really useful here where I work, we got slow PC machines and VS2015 loads at turtle speed.

thanks for your tips. :D

Comment: from what I know VSCode doesn't support such a thing, but you could write a task that uses csc.exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't.  Visual Studio Code is simply an editor.  You would need to invoke the .Net Compiler via the command-line tools.  More information about those tools can be found on the [Visual Studio Code web-site](https://github.com/dotnet/cli).

You would need to open the command line, point to the application directory, then do:

```
dotnet run
dotnet build
```

Please keep in mind those commands won't work until you install all the required .Net binaries, for your platform.

Comment: @Alex Yes, those commands are .Net Core.  But you still have the original  csc.exe option `csc /t:library /out:MyCode.dll example.cs` Since he mentioned MVC, I assumed that to use Core would be an easy approach.  Or easier migration I suppose.

Comment: he has MVC 5, not Core, and not sure if he wants to migrate. And yes, .NET Core you can run without VS and even on Mac and Linux.

Comment: @Alex I know he has MVC 5, the migration path to core from that is pretty painless.

Comment: Thanks @Greg so If we migrate the webApplication to .Net Core MVC would it be possible by compiling it with the CLI. But the other class library projects modifications?